# What URL should I use to PUT an update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have a Rails app that I just picked up that has the following command in "rake routes":

```
PUT    /testclass/:id(.:format)                      testclass#update
```

I want to send a PUT update to this `testclass` with the `id` 18445 and change `finished` to false:

```
/18445&finished=false
```

for example.

My understanding is this should be able to be done by a HTTP request in the browser, for example, can it? Or do I need to use a Ruby command?
Any guidance?

Comment: Question is not clear, unable to understand what exactly are you asking

Comment: You could look into Advanced REST Client in Chrome and just send a put request without creating a form if all you want to do is test it. Hopefully this helps.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Comment: But, in your estimation, IS that a possibility? I SHOULD be able to pass this in HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a ruby command to access that route to make an update.

Basic HTML will look something like this (you can edit the action to be relevant to your route):

```
    <form action='testclass/18445' method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
      <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
      <input type="hidden" name="testclass[id]" value="18445" >
      <input type="hidden" name="testclass[finished]" value="false" >
      <input type="submit" value="update" >
    </form>
```

Notice it is a 'post' but there is a hidden input with the name '_method' and value 'put'. Hopefully this is what you're looking for. You can send your id through a hidden input, same with the false value.

Comment: Ok so I need to make this a form - I get the action, that should be good to go. Then there's a hidden input to make it a post, I get that. So if my actually item is auction2 and the value is DONE I want to do like <input type="checkbox" name="auction2[done]">

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the update - are you suggested I do <input type="hidden" name="done" value="false">

Comment: Nevermind - I see <input type="hidden" name="auction2[done]" value="false" >

Comment: Ok well I can only accept the answer, I can not upvote, but I hope others will! That's a great answer, I was combing SO for hours before getting this, only because it's such a dead simple question that most people have more complex ones. Great for newbies like me!

Comment: No problem, glad I can help. Rails is full of metaprogramming and hidden stuff under the hood, so the hidden 'put' value and even maybe token is not very obvious to most users who haven't dug into it. Most users will probably use "Simple Form" or "FormHelper" to create this form and not see this stuff.